# How to remoisten sweetened coconut after opening?

Tags: coconut

My Baker's sweetened coconut is not moist after being stored in the refrigerator. How can it be remoistened?

Comment: try soaking it in coconut water or coconut milk.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link from eHow that walks through how to moisten coconut flakes: 
http://www.ehow.com/how_8278347_moisten-dry-coconut-flakes.html

Although you are working with sweetened coconut that was once moist, this approach may still work.  They recommend you do the following:

1. Put a pan of water on the stove and bring it to a boil
2. Place a colander over the pan and put the coconut in the colander
3. Let the coconut absorb the steam for a few minutes and then pull the coconut off and pat dry it with a towel